# Segmentation fault when free MKL pointer after called lapacke hesv routine

Tags: c, intel-mkl

I'm developing a code to invert a matrix using lapacke interface for C language. I used the intel mkl library to do such a job. Nevertheless when I try out the simple test to invert a matrix of variable size N I get an undefined behavior when I free the pointer of the matrix. What is strange is because it works if N = 3 but stop working with N >= 4, for instance if I do not free the pointer the code runs perfectly for any value of N. The other pointers the function requires I can free without any trouble. Any ideas?

Additional information: I'm using the zhesv function that can solve multiple linear systems. The API can be found at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520994

The code I'm trying to run:

```
/*
 * compile with intel mkl installation:
 *
 * gcc -o test exe/lapack_inversion_test.c  -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-    needed -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lm -ldl
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mkl.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.141592653589793 // to define matrix entries

#define LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR 101
#define LAPACK_COL_MAJOR 102

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int j, // counter
        i, // counter
        N, // The size of the Matrix
        k;

    double arg;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);

    int * ipiv = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    MKL_Complex16 x; x.real = 0; x.imag = 0;
    MKL_Complex16 * A = malloc(N * N * sizeof(MKL_Complex16));
    MKL_Complex16 * Acopy = malloc(N * N * sizeof(MKL_Complex16));
    MKL_Complex16 * Id = malloc(N * N * sizeof(MKL_Complex16));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {   // Row major storage
        A[i * N + i].real = 1.5 + sin( 3 * PI * i / N );
        A[i * N + i].imag = 0;
        Acopy[i * N + i].real = 1.5 + sin( 3 * PI * i / N );
        Acopy[i * N + i].imag = 0;
        Id[i * N + i].real = 1;
        Id[i * N + i].imag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            arg = 10 * PI * ((double) i * j) / (N * N);
            A[i * N + j].real = 2 * sin(arg) + 2;
            A[i * N + j].imag = 3 * cos(arg);
            A[j * N + i].real = 0; // Does not matter the upper tirangular
            A[j * N + i].imag = 0; // when call lapack routine with 'L'

            Acopy[i * N + j].real = 2 * sin(arg) + 2;
            Acopy[i * N + j].imag = 3 * cos(arg);
            Acopy[j * N + i].real = Acopy[i * N + j].real;
            Acopy[j * N + i].imag = - Acopy[i * N + j].imag;

            Id[i * N + j].real = 0; // Identity
            Id[i * N + j].imag = 0;
            Id[j * N + i].real = 0;
            Id[j * N + i].imag = 0;
        }
    }

    i = LAPACKE_zhesv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'L', N, N, A, N, ipiv, Id, N);
    printf("\n\nLapacke returned : %d\n", i);

    printf("\n\nIf there was any problem print identity: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t|");
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            x.real = 0;
            x.imag = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                x.real += Id[i*N + k].real * Acopy[k*N + j].real;
                x.real -= Id[i*N + k].imag * Acopy[k*N + j].imag;
                x.imag += Id[i*N + k].real * Acopy[k*N + j].imag;
                x.imag += Id[i*N + k].imag * Acopy[k*N + j].real;
            }
            printf(" (%6.3lf,%6.3lf) |", x.real, x.imag);
        }
    }

    // free(A); if one try to free does not work with N >= 4 !!!!
    free(Id);
    free(ipiv);

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If we let the code free(A) (uncomment) the it does:

$ ./test 3

Lapacke returned : 0

If there was any problem print identity:

```
| ( 1.000,-0.000) | ( 0.000,-0.000) | (-0.000,-0.000) |
| ( 0.000, 0.000) | ( 1.000, 0.000) | ( 0.000, 0.000) |
| (-0.000,-0.000) | (-0.000, 0.000) | ( 1.000, 0.000) |
```

$ ./test 4

Lapacke returned : 0

If there was any problem print identity:

```
| ( 1.000,-0.000) | ( 0.000,-0.000) | ( 0.000, 0.000) | (-0.000, 0.000) |
| (-0.000, 0.000) | ( 1.000, 0.000) | ( 0.000, 0.000) | (-0.000, 0.000) |
| (-0.000, 0.000) | (-0.000, 0.000) | ( 1.000,-0.000) | (-0.000,-0.000) |
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: The value of `i`  (returned from the LAPACKE_zhesv) is always 0?

Comment: Not reproducible. N=4 to N=8 works for me.

Comment: Yes the value returned is zero if the inversion could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `LAPACKE_zhesv`'s declaration:

```
lapack_int LAPACKE_zhesv(int matrix_layout, char uplo, lapack_int n, lapack_int nrhs, lapack_complex_double* a, lapack_int lda, lapack_int* ipiv, lapack_complex_double* b , lapack_int ldb);
```

In particular, it wants `lapack_int* ipiv`, but you declare it as `int* ipiv`. Then you link your program with `mkl_intel_ilp64` and [do not define](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-macos-developer-guide-using-the-ilp64-interface-vs-lp64-interface) `MKL_ILP64`. Your program and MKL end up using incompatible integral types: `sizeof(int) = 4`, whereas `sizeof(lapack_int) = 8`.

Quick fix is to link with `mkl_intel_lp64`. But you should rewrite your code to use `lapack_int` instead of `int`, then it'll work correctly both with `LP64` and `ILP64`.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked just changing the compile options. I use now the link -lmkl_intel_lp64 instead of _ilp64. This way It work both lapack_int and int * as well.

Comment: @AlexAndriati, if `MKL_ILP64` is not defined, then it is effectively `#define lapack_int int` in MKL headers.